# BigInteger.Parse() on hexadecimal number gives negative numbers

Tags: parsing, .net-4.0, hex, biginteger

I've started using .NET 4 [System.Numerics.BigInteger Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and I've encountered a problem.

I'm trying to parse a string that contains a hexadecimal number with no sign (positive). I'm getting a negative number.

For example, I do the following two asserts:

```
Assert.IsTrue(System.Int64.Parse("8", NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > 0, "Int64");
Assert.IsTrue(System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("8", NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > 0, "BigInteger");
```

The first assert succeeds, the second assert fails. I actually get -8 instead of 8 in the `BigInteger`.

The problem seems to be when I'm the hexadecimal starts with 1 bit and not 0 bit (a digit between 8 and F inclusive). If I add a leading 0, everything works perfectly.

Is that a bad usage on my part? Is it a bug in `BigInteger`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's exactly what the method is supposed to do.

[MSDN: BigInteger.Parse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268285.aspx):

> "If value is a hexadecimal string, the
>   Parse(String, NumberStyles) method
>   interprets value as a negative number
>   stored by using two's complement
>   representation if its first two
>   hexadecimal digits are greater than or
>   equal to 0x80. In other words, the
>   method interprets the highest-order
>   bit of the first byte in value  as the
>   sign bit. To make sure that a
>   hexadecimal string is correctly
>   interpreted as a positive number, the
>   first digit in value must have a value
>   of zero. For example, the method
>   interprets 0x80 as a negative value,
>   but it interprets either 0x080  or
>   0x0080 as a positive value."

Comment: Why? Is there a comp sci reason to do this?