# C# byte array calculation with BigInteger not working properly

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, biginteger, calculation

So, i need to calculate byte arrays in my program and i noticed weird thing:

```
        string aaa = "F8F9FAFBFCFD";
        string aaaah = "10101010101";
        BigInteger dsa = BigInteger.Parse(aaa, NumberStyles.HexNumber) + BigInteger.Parse(aaaah, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        MessageBox.Show(dsa.ToString("X"));
```

When i add aaa + aaah, it displays me 9FAFBFCFDFE, but it should display F9FAFBFCFDFE, but when i subtract it does it right, aaa - aaah, displays F7F8F9FAFBFC, everything should be right in my code.

Comment: When i do with longer byte arrays, it does same thing, and it starts from F8.

Comment: Make sure you are right justified.  The two number are different lengths.

Comment: I tried with 010101010101 too, gives same result as with 10101010101.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BigInteger.Parse() on hexadecimal number gives negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983706/biginteger-parse-on-hexadecimal-number-gives-negative-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BigInteger.Parse` interprets `"F8F9FAFBFCFD"` as the negative number -7,722,435,347,203 (using two's complement) and not 273,752,541,363,453 as you were probably expecting.

From the [documentation for `BigInteger.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> If `value` is a hexadecimal string, the `Parse(String, NumberStyles)`
>   method interprets `value` as a negative number stored by using two's
>   complement representation if its first two hexadecimal digits are
>   greater than or equal to `0x80`. In other words, the method interprets
>   the highest-order bit of the first byte in `value` as the sign bit.

To get the result you are expecting, prefix `aaa` with a 0 to force it to be interpreted as a positive value:

```
string aaa = "0F8F9FAFBFCFD";
string aaaah = "10101010101";
BigInteger dsa = BigInteger.Parse(aaa, NumberStyles.HexNumber)
               + BigInteger.Parse(aaaah, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
MessageBox.Show(dsa.ToString("X")); // outputs 0F9FAFBFCFDFE
```